# How to convert column values into dates for plotting ggplot in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

I would like to convert my column that has specific dates for each month. Ex: I converted my col that has abbreviations for each month to match the specific date data is collected. Reference below:

```
updated_df_2018$End_Date <- ifelse(updated_df_2018$Month=="Oct", "10/24/2017",
                                   ifelse(updated_df_2018$Month=="Nov", "11/28/2017",
                                          ifelse(updated_df_2018$Month=="Dec", "12/26/2017",
                                                 ifelse(updated_df_2018$Month=="Jan", "1/23/2018",
                                                        ifelse(updated_df_2018$Month=="Feb", "2/20/2018",
                                                               ifelse(updated_df_2018$Month=="Mar", "3/27/2018",
                                                                      ifelse(updated_df_2018$Month=="Apr", "4/24/2018",
                                                                             ifelse(updated_df_2018$Month=="May", "5/29/2018",
                                                                                    ifelse(updated_df_2018$Month=="Jun", "6/26/2018",
                                                                                           ifelse(updated_df_2018$Month=="Jul", "7/24/2018",
                                                                                                  ifelse(updated_df_2018$Month=="Aug", "8/28/2018",
                                                                                                         ifelse(updated_df_2018$Month=="Sep", "9/25/2018",
                                                                                                                NA  )))))))))))) # all other values map to NA
```

As you can see, for each month there is now a new column that has the raw date (month/day/year). However, when i plot - and put this col as my x axis - each month is sperate instead of a continuous plot.. When I use as.Date(col, "%d/m/y%") it converts but moves the date to 2020 and changes the order.

Any help would useful - would like to plot the change in overall sales for each building across the two year span (2017/18 to 2018/19).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mdy` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
updated_df_2018 %>%
         mutate(End_Date = mdy(End_Date))
```

---

Or with `anydate`

```
library(anytime)
updated_df_2018 %>%
        mutate(End_Date = anydate(End_Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `End_Date` to actual date value

```
updated_df_2018$End_Date <- as.Date(updated_df_2018$End_Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

and then you can use this column for plotting purposes.

Also have a look at `?scale_x_date` in case you want to manually update the x-axis.

Comment: I used your command but it converts my date to 2020 for whatever reason..

Comment: @Dinho Can you share `dput(head(updated_df_2018$End_Date))` ?

Comment: structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1/23/2018", 
"10/24/2017", "11/28/2017", "12/26/2017", "2/20/2018", "3/27/2018", 
"4/24/2018", "5/29/2018", "6/26/2018", "7/24/2018", "8/28/2018", 
"9/25/2018"), class = "factor")

Comment: How does this converts date to 2020 ? If I use `x <- structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1/23/2018", "10/24/2017", "11/28/2017", "12/26/2017", "2/20/2018", "3/27/2018", "4/24/2018", "5/29/2018", "6/26/2018", "7/24/2018", "8/28/2018", "9/25/2018"), class = "factor")` and  then `as.Date(x, "%m/%d/%Y")` it gives proper dates to me. What output does it give for you ?

Comment: it changes the year to 2020 - and then just keeps the month, day for each value. So when I run it it turns column values to 2020-10-24, 2020-11-28, etc..

Comment: @Dinho Can you restart your R session and try the above code `x <- structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1/23/2018", "10/24/2017", "11/28/2017", "12/26/2017", "2/20/2018", "3/27/2018", "4/24/2018", "5/29/2018", "6/26/2018", "7/24/2018", "8/28/2018", "9/25/2018"), class = "factor")` and `as.Date(x, "%m/%d/%Y")` . Can you paste the output of what you get here ?